# Why did Jabba keep Han around?

Tags: star-wars, return-of-the-jedi, han-solo, jabba-the-hutt

When Han arrived before Jabba, he was carbon-frozen and thus a very suitable wall display as a trophy for Jabba and a warning to visitors of his palace of the folly of incurring the great Jabba's wrath.

After Leia melted him out, there doesn't seem to be any reason for Jabba to keep him around, given that he is no longer willing to accept repayment from Han. Keeping him around will just be another mouth to feed.

So why did Jabba keep him around for Luke to rescue after Leia's botched attempt?

Comment: Is there any way I could improve my answer?

Answer (score 6):

### He didn't really keep Han around for all that long.

> THREEPIO: Oh, dear. His High Exaltedness, the great Jabba the Hutt, has decreed 
>   that you are to be terminated immediately.
>
> HAN: Good, I hate long waits.

Jabba kept Han for less than a day before attempting to execute him with the Sarlacc. He likely didn't have to feed him.

Additionally, this was a matter of honor, not money, for Jabba.

> HAN:
>   Hey, Jabba. Look, Jabba, I was just on my way to pay you back, but I 
>   got a little sidetracked. It's not my fault.
>
> Jabba laughs.
>
> JABBA (in Huttese subtitled):
>   It's too late for that, Solo. You may have been a good smuggler, but 
>   now you're Bantha fodder.
>
> HAN:
>   Look...
>
> JABBA (cont Huttese subtitled):
>   Take him away!
>
> The guards grab Han and start to lead him away.
>
> HAN: Jabba... I'll pay you triple! You're throwing away a fortune here. 
>   Don't be a fool!

([Source](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-Return-of-the-Jedi.html))